# Issue with play music

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having a problem with my games background music. When my initial view controller loads it plays the song and loops fine. I want to make it so when I change to a different view controller it stops the song.

At the moment I have made an IBAction with a button on the main view controller that successfully stops the music when I press it but if I load the initial view twice before pressing it, it will not stop the music.

Code for Initial view controller implementation file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *music = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beat" ofType:@"wav"];
    MusicPlay=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:music] error:NULL];
    MusicPlay.delegate=self;
    MusicPlay.numberOfLoops=-1;

    MusicSituation = MusicSituation + 1;

    if(MusicSituation == 1)

        [MusicPlay play];

    }
```

Code for IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender {        
    [MusicPlay stop];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if I load the initial view twice"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, definitely need more information such as "How are you navigating your controllers?".

And as asked in comment: What do you mean by "if I load the initial view twice"?

But the way you set up your player is fine and you could leave your code as is and make changes to the following:

Remove `[Music play];` from `viewDidLoad` and instead place it in `viewDidAppear`.

Then, add `[Music stop];` in `viewWillDisappear`.

If you do as mentioned above, I think you could remove your `MusicSituation` as well, because as I assume, this is the check you set post-implementation just to make sure the sound goes off as you want it to. With the above method, you wouldn't need that anymore.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a quick question, If I want it to keep playing through another view controller what do i do?

Comment: @user3752308 In such case, I would suggest not stopping the audio at all, let it simply play.

Comment: I basically want the music to play throughout the main and settings view controller but stop when i go into the game view controller

Answer (score 0):

First o all, the code in viewDidLoad should be able to run multiple times with out any issues. If you check apple docs, you will see that some actions can make a view to reload.

First check if MusicPlay is nil before creating another instance of AVAudioPlayer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *music = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beat" ofType:@"wav"];

    if (MusicPlay==nil){
      MusicPlay=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:music] error:NULL];
      MusicPlay.delegate=self;
      MusicPlay.numberOfLoops=-1;

      MusicSituation = MusicSituation + 1;

      if(MusicSituation == 1)

          [MusicPlay play];

      }
   }
```

And you also should think what is happening in you app for the viewDidLoad to be called twice.

Comment: I have a settings page that you go to from the main controller and when I come back from it, it loads the viewdidload again